# How to Control the time between each Post Using Facebook Sdk C#

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook Sdk C# To develop a desktop program for publication posts in Facebook groups. The software will publish very quickly I need a way to control the speed of publication and capping for publication not less than 10 seconds between each publication and the other. How to do like this methods ?

My class

```
        public static string UploadPost(string groupid, string intTitle, string inMessage, string inLinkCaption, string inLinkUrl, string inLinkDescription, string inLinkUrlPicture)
    {
        object obj;
        Facebook.JsonObject jsonObj;
        FacebookClient client;
        string access_token = AppSettings.Default.AccessToken.ToString();

        client = new FacebookClient(access_token);

        var args = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        args["message"] = inMessage;
        args["caption"] = inLinkCaption;
        args["description"] = inLinkDescription;
        args["name"] = intTitle;
        args["picture"] = inLinkUrlPicture;
        args["link"] = inLinkUrl;

        if ((obj = client.Post("/" + groupid + "/feed", args)) != null)
        {
            if ((jsonObj = obj as Facebook.JsonObject) != null)
            {
                if (jsonObj.Count > 0)
                    return jsonObj[0].ToString();
            }
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }

    internal static bool UploadPost(string p1, string p2)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

}

My submit button

```
        private void btnPost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lstgroupsbox.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Class1.UploadPost(lstgroupsbox.Items[i].ToString(), "amine", txtStatus.Text, "googl", txtLink.Text, "seach", txtImagePath.Text) != string.Empty)
                label23.Text=""+lstgroups.Items[i].Text;
        }
        //foreach (var item in lstgroupsbox.Items)
        //{
        //    if (Class1.UploadPost(item.ToString(), "amine", txtStatus.Text, "googl", 2, "seach", txtImagePath.Text) != string.Empty)
        //        label23.Text=""+lstgroups.Items[i].Text;
        //}

    }
```

Comment: Why is it publishing multiple times in rapid succession? Did you place it inside a loop or something? Instead, use a `Timer` if you want to do your publishing every 10 seconds.

Comment: Did you place it inside a loop or something? no sir , and how i can using Timer to control in this operation , sorry for this cuze am beginner in c#

Comment: Can you show your whole code? I'm trying to understand why it "publishes very quickly"

Comment: And by that I mean please update your question to include the rest of the relevant code :)

Comment: okay sir thank you and i will update now my Questions

Comment: i Edit  now i hope to find solution for my problem

Comment: I added the code example.

Comment: Thanks all thanks to you to help me and sorry for the delay in responding to some Internet connection problems
I'm going to put code now and respond to you the result
Thank you @GrawCube

Comment: @GrawCube Sloved my problem Thanks for hime  ٍ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you look into the [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) class. This one way you could do this:

Create a `ConcurrentQueue` (not a normal Queue because it's not *thread-safe*, look into *thread safety*) in your main class. This is your upload "job list". Add also a Timer and create an event handler method for its `Elapsed` event (refer to the first link in this answer for instructions). The event handler method is what will execute your jobs.

Then create a new class that holds a post's info and the details needed to upload it. This is your upload job class.

In your `for loop` inside your submit button's event handler, instead of uploading the images, you create instances of that job class and enqueue them into your job list (the ConcurrentQueue). After they're all added, you start your main class' Timer. The `Elapsed` event handler method mentioned earlier will take the next item from the queue (or stop if it's empty?) and upload it to Facebook.

EDIT:
So, in your form class, add a using statement first:

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
```

Then add these near the top of the class:

```
private System.Timers.Timer _jobTimer = new Timer(10000);

private ConcurrentQueue<UploadJob> _jobQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<UploadJob>();
```

These go to your form's constructor (after the `InitializeComponent()` method call):

```
_jobTimer.SynchronizingObject = this;
// ^  The Elapsed event will be run on the same thread as this.
//    This way we won't get exceptions for trying to access the form's labels 
//    from another thread (the Timer is run on its own thread).
_jobTimer.Elapsed += OnJobTimedEvent;
```

Then you add the `OnJobTimedEvent` method somewhere in your form class:

```
private void OnJobTimedEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    UploadJob job;
    if (_jobQueue.TryDequeue(out job)) // Returns false if it fails to return the next object from the queue
    {
        if (Class1.UploadPost(job.Group,
            job.Name,
            job.Message,
            job.Caption,
            job.Link,
            job.Description,
            job.Picture) != string.Empty)
        {
            // Post was uploaded successfully
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // I believe we can assume that the job queue is empty.
        // I'm not sure about the conditions under which TryDequeue will fail
        // but if "no more elements" isn't the only one, we could add
        // (_jobQueue.Count == 0)
        // to the if statement above
        _jobTimer.Stop();
        // All uploads complete
    }
}
```

As you can see, it uses `UploadJob`. That class can be separated into a separate file altogether:

```
public class UploadJob
{
    public string Group { get; protected set; }

    public string Name { get; protected set; }

    public string Message { get; protected set; }

    public string Caption { get; protected set; }

    public string Link { get; protected set; }

    public string Description { get; protected set; }

    public string Picture { get; protected set; }

    public UploadJob(string group,
                     string name,
                     string message,
                     string caption,
                     string link,
                     string description,
                     string picture)
    {
        Group = group;
        Name = name;
        Message = message;
        Caption = caption;
        Link = link;
        Description = description;
        Picture = picture;
    }
}
```

and finally we get to your button click event handler:

```
private void btnPost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lstgroupsbox.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        _jobQueue.Enqueue(lstgroupsbox.Items[i].ToString(),
            "amine",
            txtStatus.Text,
            "googl",
            txtLink.Text,
            "seach",
            txtImagePath.Text);
    }
    _jobTimer.Start();
}
```

Personally I would probably separate all this into an UploadManager class or something and let that class worry about the timer and everything, but this should work just fine.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer sir any way i will try but please no forget the code " i wait the code  tomorrow  , cuze from 1 weak i try to do this and every time not success

Comment: @user4464587 You should not give up that easily! Look up the classes and terms you don't know  and try to understand them. Give it a shot - you'll be surprised.

Comment: okay am try right now to do this but i have question , this edit should be in submit button ?